# Linq to NHibernate repository implementation details

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'd like to have the following API for my `MyTypeRepository`:

```
var myChosenInstance = _myRepository.FindOne(x => x.MyProperty == "MyValue");
```

..and for the lambda to use used to construct a linq query within the repository, which is then used by Linq to NHibernate.

Is this possible? What would my repository FindOne method look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public EntityType FindOne<EntityType>(Expression<Func<EntityType,bool>> predicate)
{
    return session.Linq<EntityType>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

I'm assuming

1. that your repository class has an `ISession` variable called `session`
2. that Linq-To-NHibernate has a working implementation of the `FirstOrDefault()` method (because I haven't tested it to confirm)

If your repository class has a type parameter `Repository<EntityType>`, then you can omit the type parameter from the method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var f = new Func<MyType, bool>(x => x.MyProperty == "MyValue");
var query = from t in session.Linq<MyType>() 
            where f.Invoke(t) 
            select new { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name };
//or...
var query = from c in collection 
            .Where(f) 
            select new { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name };
var results = query.Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

AS an alternative, [here](http://gist.github.com/459517) is a repository interface and implementation that exposes generic `IQueryable`, `ICollection` and `IDictionary` interfaces.

When using that, you just use LINQ extension methods for querying, i.e. `repository.Single(lambda)`, etc.